# How to actively logoff a user with go-guardian JWT strategy?

Tags: go, jwt, go-guardian

I'm using go-guardian with the JWT "basic-bearer" strategy for authentication in my project and it works really nice. When the client has no token, he logs in with his credentials and receives a JWT, which he can then use for further requests like this one:

```
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    },
                    url: '/api/archive',
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(searchData),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: onDataReceived,
                    error: onError
                });
```

However, I wonder how to do an active logoff on the server side when the client hits the `/auth/logoff` route, for example? Sure, the client can simply delete the token, but then the server would still accept it. How can I actively invalidate or remove a token on the server side, so that I can safely say that the client has to reauthenticate?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about this recently myself. But haven't explored. It seems the cache has a Delete() method that may do the trick: https://github.com/shaj13/go-guardian/blob/master/auth/cache.go

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, too. I think there probably should be a function for invalidating a user, maybe it's just not implemented yet. I'll have a look at the cache.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep a separate table `user_session` where the session also includes the token of the user. When an endpoint is hit you check the signature of the token and also if that token is in the database.

You also need to store the token when users are logged in, and remove this token when users are logged out.

The reason you need multiple sessions per user is because users might log in from separate devices using multiple tokens. To logoff a user you can delete that particular session from `user_session` or to logoff from all devices you can remove all sessions of that user.